# Why did Apache IoTDB reported target file incomplete when merging tsfile?

Tags: database, merge, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When I tried to compact and merge tsfile of Apache IoTDB, an error kept popping out "target file is incomplete, error occurred in compaction merge thread". Does anyone know how to fix this kind of error that IoTDB kept reporting? I am using Version 0.12.5 now.

I also checked the issues on Github, but still cannot find answer to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The merged tsfile is incomplete. You need to stop all writing progress in Apache IoTDB, and start flush operation. See if this solve your error problem.